# matplotlib の plot_surface で AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim' というエラーが出る

Tags: python, matplotlib

## 前提・実現したいこと

python3.6を使ってFDTD法の計算結果を描画したいと考えています。
しかし、計算自体は行えたのですが、描画をする際にエラーが出ます。
エラーコードを読むに、Main FDTD Loopの中の計算には問題がなく、その後のmatplotlibの部分に問題があると思うのですが、どうにもできず途方に暮れています。
ソースコードの
gaz_arrange.txt
gbz_arrange.txt
は、200x200の配列(?)を入れたテキストファイルです。
ie,je,ia,ibなどは全て整数値です。

以下がエラーメッセージです。

```
C:\Users\USER\python\FDTD\ELECTROMAGNETIC SIMULATION USING THE FDTD> python fd2d
_main.py
100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 194/194 [00:01<00:00, 135.79it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 300/300 [03:47<00:00,  1.32it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fd2d_main.py", line 123, in <module>
    plot_e_field(ax,  plotting_point[ 'data_to_plot'], plotting_point[ 'num_step
s'], plotting_point['label'])
  File "fd2d_main.py", line 105, in plot_e_field
    ax.plot_surface(Y, X, data,  rstride=1,  cstride=1, color='white', edgecolor
='black',  linewidth=.25)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\m
pl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1555, in plot_surface
    if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

また、次のものがソースコードです。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
fd2d メインのプログラム
"""

import  numpy  as  np 
import scipy.constants as sc
from  math  import  pi, sin, cos
from  matplotlib  import  pyplot  as  plt 
from  mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d  import  Axes3D, get_test_data
from tqdm import tqdm

import fd2d_scatter_arrange as fs
import fd2d_init_value as fi


# 誘電体の配置の読み込み
gaz = np.loadtxt('gaz_arrange.txt')
gbz = np.loadtxt('gbz_arrange.txt')

# Dictionary  to  keep  track  of  desired  points  for plotting 
plotting_points =  [{'label': 'a','num_steps':4700, 'data_to_plot':None}, {'label':'b', 'num_steps':4800, 'data_to_plot':None}, { 'label':'c' ,'num_steps':4900, 'data_to_plot':None}, {'label':'d', 'num_steps':5000, 'data_to_plot':None}, ] 

# Main  FDTD Loop 
for  time_step  in  tqdm( range(1,  fi.nsteps  + 1) ):

    # Incident Ez values
    for j in  range(1, fi.je): 
        fi.ez_inc[j] = fi.ez_inc[j]  + 0.5  * (fi.hx_inc[j - 1] - fi.hx_inc[j])

    # Absorbing Boundary  Conditions 
    fi.ez_inc[0] = fi.boundary_low.pop(0)
    fi.boundary_low.append(fi.ez_inc[1])
    fi.ez_inc[fi.je  - 1] =  fi.boundary_high.pop(0)
    fi.boundary_high.append(fi.ez_inc[fi.je  - 2])

    # Calculate  the  Dz field 
    for j in  range(1, fi.je): 
        for  i in  range(1,  fi.ie): 
            fi.dz[i, j]  =  fi.gi3[i] *  fi.gj3[j] *  fi.dz[i, j]  + fi.gi2[i] *  fi.gj2[j] * 0.5 * (fi.hy[i,  j]  - fi.hy[i  - 1, j] - fi.hx[i, j]  +  fi.hx[i, j - 1]) 

    # Source 
    pulse =  sin(2 * pi * fi.freq * fi.dt * (fi.t0 - time_step))
    fi.ez_inc[3] =  pulse

    # Incident  Dz values 
    for  i in  range(fi.ia,  fi.ib): 
        fi.dz[i, fi.ja] =  fi.dz[i, fi.ja]  + 0.5 * fi.hx_inc[fi.ja  - 1 ] 
        fi.dz[i, fi.jb] =  fi.dz[i, fi.jb] - 0.5 * fi.hx_inc[fi.jb - 1 ]

    # Calculate the Ez field
    for j in range(0, fi.je):
        for i in range(0, fi.ie):
            fi.ez[i, j] = gaz[i, j] * (fi.dz[i, j] - fi.iz[i,j])
            fi.iz[i, j] = fi.iz[i, j] + gbz[i, j] * fi.ez[i,j]

    # Calculate the Incident Hx
    for j in  range(0, fi.je  - 1): 
        fi.hx_inc[j] = fi.hx_inc[j]  + 0.5  * (fi.ez_inc[j] - fi.ez_inc[j  + 1])

    # Calculate the Hx field
    for j in  range(0, fi.je  - 1):
        for  i in  range(0,  fi.ie  - 1): 
            curl_e =  fi.ez[i,  j]  - fi.ez[i, j + 1]
            fi.ihx[i,  j]  =  fi.ihx[i,  j]  + curl_e
            fi.hx[i, j]  =  fi.fj3[j]  *  fi.hx[i, j]  + fi.fj2[j]  * (0.5  *  curl_e + fi.fil[i]  *  fi.ihx[i,j])

    # Incident  Hx values 
    for  i in  range(fi.ia,  fi.ib): 
        fi.hx[i, fi.ja  - 1]  =  fi.hx[i, fi.ja  - 1]  + 0.5 * fi.ez_inc[fi.ja] 
        fi.hx[i, fi.jb]  =  fi.hx[i, fi.jb] - 0.5  *  fi.ez_inc[fi.jb]

    # Calculate  the  Hy field 
    for j in  range(0, fi.je  - 1): 
        for  i in  range(0,  fi.ie  - 1): 
            curl_e =  fi.ez[i,  j]  - fi.ez[i  + 1,  j]
            fi.ihy[i,  j]  =  fi.ihy[i,  j]  + curl_e
            fi.hy[i, j]  =  fi.fi3[i]  *  fi.hy[i, j] - fi.fi2[i]  * (0.5  *  curl_e + fi.fjl[j]  *  fi.ihy[i,j])

    # Incident  Hy values 
    for j in  range(fi.ja, fi.jb): 
        fi.hy[fi.ia  - 1,  j]  =  fi.hy[fi.ia  - 1,  j]  - 0.5  *  fi.ez_inc[j]
        fi.hy[fi.ib  - 1,  j]  =  fi.hy[fi.ib  - 1,  j]  + 0.5  *  fi.ez_inc[j]

    # Save  data  at  certain  points  for  later  plotting 
    for  plotting_point  in  plotting_points:
        if  time_step ==  plotting_point['num_steps']:
            plotting_point['data_to_plot'] = np.copy(fi.ez)


# Plot  Fig
plt.rcParams['font.size']=  12 
plt.rcParams['grid.color']=  'gray' 
plt.rcParams['grid.linestyle']  = 'dotted' 
fig =  plt.figure(figsize=(8,  8)) 

X, Y  =  np.meshgrid(range(fi.je),  range(fi.ie)) 

def  plot_e_field(ax,  data,  timestep,  label):
    """3d  Plot  of  E field  at  a single  timestep""" 
    ax.set_zlim(-0.5, 1)
    ax.view_init(elev=15, azim=25)
    ax.plot_surface(Y, X, np.array(data),  rstride=1,  cstride=1, color='white', edgecolor='black',  linewidth=.25) 
    ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False)
    ax.set_zlabel(r' $E_{Z}$',  rotation=90, labelpad=10, fontsize=14) 
    ax.set_zticks([-0.5, 0, 0.5,  1])
    ax.set_xlabel('cm')
    ax.set_ylabel('cm')
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 200, step=50))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 200, step=50))
    ax.text2D( 0.25, 0.3, "T = {}".format(timestep) , transform=ax.transAxes) 
    ax.xaxis.pane.fill  =  ax.yaxis.pane.fill  = ax.zaxis.pane.fill  =  False 
    plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor( 'white')
    ax.text2D(-0.05,  0.8, "( {} ) ".format(label), transform=ax.transAxes) 
    ax.dist =  11


# Plot  the  E field  at  each  of  the  four  time  steps saved  earlier 
for  subplot_num, plotting_point  in enumerate(plotting_points):
    ax =  fig.add_subplot(2, 2,  subplot_num + 1, projection='3d' ) 
    plot_e_field(ax,  plotting_point[ 'data_to_plot'], plotting_point[ 'num_steps'], plotting_point['label']) 

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("image.png")
plt.show()
```

## 試したこと

plot_surfaceの最初の引数3つの内に問題があると思い、dataをNumpy配列にしてみたのですが駄目でした。
また、コードを書いた当初は問題なく実行できていたのですが、zticksとxticks、yticksの値を変更した後にエラーが出るようになりました。
この部分に問題があるのかと値を戻したところ、エラーのみが残ってしまいました。
元々はplt.savefig("image.png")の行で終わっていたのですが、その後にplt.show()が合った方が挙動が安定するという話を聞きましたので、エラーを吐くようになってから文を追加しました。

## 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

matplotlib      3.3.4
numpy           1.19.5

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/377125) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: @Shiba Samo さん、マルチポスト先で解決したようなので、それを反映して自己回答にでもしてみてください。